# How to open an URL with Selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium

Problem:

I just want to open a URL with selenium in python but it didn't work.

This is my current code:

```
from selenium import webdriver 

path='C:\Program Files (x86)\chromdriver.exe'
url='https://anywebpage.de'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(path)
```

Technical specification:

Windows 10 Pro 64 bit Python Version 3.9

I get this error message:

"Message: 'chromdriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see [https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home"](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home%22)

I cannot find a solution out in the documentation

Has anyone else an idea?

The exe.file is in the correct path stored.

Comment: Did you spell chromedriver.exe wrong? Don't forget the e after chrom

Comment: THANKS a lot i missed the "e"

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
PATH = "C:\Chrome Webdriver\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("Your-website-here")
```

If you are using windows, press shift and right click on chromedriver to copy it's path [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ab0Lq.png)

"C:\Chrome Webdriver\chromedriver.exe" was my own personal path, you must copy yours.

Also, in your code above, your file path is missing an "e" in chromedriver